# Bing browser App on Android can't handle firebase dynamic links URL

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links, bing, mobile-browser

When I open the URL created on firebase dynamic links via Bing browser App on Android,
It seems like Bing App can't handle the link and shows a blank screen.

[Bing Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDhDX.png)

The URL works on iOS or other browser apps.
And it doesn't work on neither click nor type into browser.

It'll be great if you let me know any workaround
or way to contact to Microsoft Bing support.

Dynamic links URL works as usual on Bing browser app on Android.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community this issue doesn't depend on codes, bot

Comment: Same issue is happening with me